# RegEx to include two words, but exclude a space followed by anything that isn't a space at the end of the string

Tags: regex

I'm dealing with names and I'm trying to match "First Last", but not "First Last Middle." I think the tricky part is I do want to allow any whitespace at the end, just not whitespace followed by anything else. This is what I have:

`^([^\s]+[\s]+)([^\s])$`

This will almost work, but it excludes "First Last" with spaces at the end and I want to allow for sloppy data entry like that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string to be searched and the desired results as well? If you are dealing with names...how do you know the difference between a first anme and middle name?

Comment: Sometimes Surnames have spaces in. For example, former England cricket player "Philip De Freitas", so you may need to re-think what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the pattern, lookahead for zero or more spaces, followed by the end of the string:

```
^(\S+\s+)(\S+)(?=\s*$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/PjGPAw/1

Also note that whenever you have a character set with just one token (like `\s`), you can remove the character set entirely and just use that token. In addition, the negation of `\s` (that is, the character set `[^\s]`) is equivalent to `\S`, which means "anything but a whitespace character", and is probably preferable to `[^\s]`.

Comment: What were to happen if the person had 2 or more names in any of the names? Honestly asking.. not sure if the OP considered this.